# Input Data for spam detector

Tags: svm, spam

I am trying to develop a spam detector application using svm classifier.
But I am not able to find any input data. Can anyone please suggest what kind of input data should I take and from where I could find it. I tried google but didnt found the satisfactory answeres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stanford machine learning course (ml-class.org) has a lab (no. 6) where you build a spam 
filter using support vector machines. The dataset is supplied.